# Unable to feed a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im using the following code for prediction

```
roi = frame[t_y:t_y + t_h, t_x:t_x + t_w]


predictions = sess.run(classification_tensor, feed_dict={'age_model/input_1:0': roi})
```

however Im getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/R&D/Documents/Maxis_2/Maxis/src/dwell_time_maxis.py", line 207, in <module>
    predictions = sess.run(age_tensor, feed_dict={'age_model/input_1:0': roi})
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 975, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 64, 3) for Tensor 'age_model/input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 64, 64, 3)' .
```

Though I have resized it to 64x64x3, Im still getting this error. why so?

Comment: Did you try `feed_dict={'age_model/input_1:0': roi[None]}`?

Comment: let me try it...

Comment: it is firing the same error

Comment: What does `roi[None].shape` yield? Is it four dimensional?

Comment: yes it is four dimensional

Comment: Does the dimension match `(?, 64, 64, 3)` then? That seems to be what the error indicates.

Comment: i tried roi = roi.reshape(1, 64, 64, 3) and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are feeding a 3-dimensional value into a 4 dimensional value (even if the number of element is the same).

Just reshape your feed:

```
roi = np.reshape(roi, [1,64,64,3])
```